# Nginx Zend Framework and Static Content Error

Tags: nginx, zend-framework2

Here's the relevant nginx config (This is not a pure ZF app, rather ZF is embedded)

```
location /interface/modules/zend_modules/public/ {
    root /interface/modules/zend_modules/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $document_root/$uri $document_root/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /interface/modules/zend_modules/public/(css|js|images)/ {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root /srv/app;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

`http://example.com/interface/modules/zend_modules/public/Installer` successfully returns the page, but CSS, JS, and all images are returning 404

I just can't figure out how to get my static content to not get redirectred to `index.php` (Static content is located in `.../zend_modules/public/(css|js|images)`

Comment: What does `...` mean? Is it `/srv/app/interface/modules`? Also, what is the URI of the `css` files? Is it `/interface/modules/zend_modules/public/css/foo.css`?

Comment: Yes, the ```...``` was just shorthand for ```/srv/app/interface/modules``` the URI of the css is indeed what you think

```/interface/modules/zend_modules/public/css/foo.css```, 
```/interface/modules/zend_modules/public/images/filename.png```, and
```/interface/modules/zend_modules/public/js/filename.js```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first location block does not work the way you expect. It simply rewrites the URI to `/interface/modules/zend_modules/public/index.php` because of your weird `root` value.

The value for `root` should be `/srv/app` for all `location` blocks, as `nginx` constructs the pathname by concatenating the `root` value with the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

You suggest that this `server` implements multiple applications, so to restrict these locations to URIs which begin `/interface/modules/zend_modules/public/` use nested locations and use the `^~` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /interface/modules/zend_modules/public {
    root /srv/app;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /interface/modules/zend_modules/public/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If multiple applications are PHP based, and share the same `root`, you could use something like this:

```
root /srv/app;

location /interface/modules/zend_modules/public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /interface/modules/zend_modules/public/index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Comment: On second look this doesn't actually solve my issue. While this does solve the ZF index redirects and static content on that page, all the other scripts located outside interface/modules/zend_modules/public are now returning 404. For instance, ```interface/library/otherfile.php``` returns 404. The ```server``` is only serving this one application (sorry for any confusion)

Comment: You can place the `root` inside the `location` block, but it is usual to allow common values of `root` to be inherited. The revised answer allows the `location ~ \.php$` block to be shared by the other applications (as you originally had it).

Comment: Solved (For real this time)